# How to change the position of a single letter/symbol (*) – gender specific typography

Tags: symbols, typography

I'd like to use an asterisk for gender specific wording. But as the asterisk is by default superscripted and there is a lot of white space between the parts of the word. To avoid this a few publishers moved the asterisk down to upper limit of the x-height.

Does someone know how to achieve this? Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
 x Autor*in
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you committed to using `*` on input not say `Autor\*in` or `Autor∗in` or even `Autor⁎in` defining `*` is possible but rather more complicated if you want to do it globally without breaking uses such as `\section*` or `\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Raise the asterisk by 1ex minus the height.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Alegreya}

\newcommand{\gs}{\raisebox{\dimexpr1ex-\height}{*}}

\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule height\dimexpr1ex+0.05pt depth -\dimexpr1ex-0.05pt width 3cm}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule height 0.05pt depth 0.05pt width 3cm}%
x Autor\gs in

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to `\renewcommand{\*}{...}` instead of `\newcommand{\gs}{...}`, but this might break other (rare) uses of `\*`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're looking for the `\textasteriskcentered` macro. Depending on the text font you employ, you may need to combine it with a suitable `\raisebox` "wrapper" instruction -- you're obviously free to choose a snappier name than `\genderstar` -- in order to get the desired vertical placement.

[image]

```
%% compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Jenson Pro} % optional
\newcommand\genderstar{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{\textasteriskcentered}}

\begin{document}
x Autor*in 

x Autor\textasteriskcentered in 

x Autor\genderstar in
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 A suggestion: I'd define a macro `\In` which does `\textasteriskcentered in` (maybe even followed by `\xspace`). In this way one types `Autor\In`, and if someone decides to use the slash instead of the asterisk, this can be easily changed for the whole document.

Comment: @campa - Thanks for this. I've updated my answer accordingly.